# PDF Generator for laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, laravel-5

I am trying to generate `PDFs` on `laravel 5.2` using `dompdf`. I want to use bootstrap **css** to style my PDF.

Can anyone please advice me on which pdf generator I can use, that can implement bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best PDF generators from HTML is [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

There Laravel wrapper is [Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy), who allows you to convert the HTML to PDF or to an image.

Comment: is this support bootstrap fonts styles ?

Comment: wkhtmltopdf  render HTML into PDF and various image formats using the Qt WebKit rendering engine, so I think it supports bootstrap styles, including the fonts

Comment: it seems under **barryvdh** im normally use `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` but its not support for bootstrap